# Custom PK field on User Model not recognized by Djoser

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I have recently switched to Djoser for my authentication service in my DRF api.

I have a slightly tweaked User model where the PK has changed from id to user_id.

When I call /auth/users/me/ I get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'id' into field. Choices are: date_joined, email, first_name, groups, user_id etc..
```

This is my current Djoser settings:

```
DJOSER = {
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'user_id',
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'email/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'bb.serializers.RegisterSerializer',
        'user_delete': 'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer'
    },
}
```

What can I do to change the target primary key to point at user_id?

Ideally I wouldn't have to change the name of the field to id as I am using this field a lot across the project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Extended User Model:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    user_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    is_connected = models.BooleanField(
        _('Connected'),
        default=False,
    )
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'bb_user'
```

Comment: Could you please post your models?

Comment: @Thorvald Thanks for the reply. I ended up switching to dj-rest-auth as I ran into another issue with Djoser. So I no longer need help with this. I've added my extended User model above anyway.